# Figure out if a test passed or not in Instanbul

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage

I am using Instanbul for generating Code coverage reports( istanbul cover _mocha test/unitTest/spec/routes/) for a MEAN application. As I have a number of test cases to run, how can I figure out how many of those got passed and how many failed as I want to deploy the code only if all the tests get passed.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the problem? What is the question? If you are looking for a tutorial then that is not what answers on this site are for. Also the "tags" on questions are for what your question is about, not for listing every technology used in the application you are working on.

Comment: I am running istanbul cover _mocha test/unitTest/spec/routes/ to generate the code coverage report but apart from this, I also want to figure out which test case got passed and which one failed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. From time to time you may receive comments like my ealier one when asking a question. Such comments are not an invitation to a conversation, but a general polite statement that your question is unclear and or lacks information such as the code you are trying to run and what problems you are facing. The response therefore is not futher comments from yourself but rather to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35883757/edit) your question with relevant information and details that would be needed in order to provide an answer.